# custom smart pointers and polynomial  number of comparison operators

Tags: c++, comparison, c++11, smart-pointers

Lets say I want to implement a smart pointer `a_ptr` which can be compared with other smart pointers.

Then I need to implement all permutations of the comparison operators:

```
template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const a_ptr<T>& a, const a_ptr<U>& b)
{
    return a.get() == b.get();
}

template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const std::shared_ptr<T>& a, const a_ptr<U>& b)
{
    return a.get() == b.get();
}

template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const a_ptr<T>& a, const std::shared_ptr<U>& b)
{
    return a.get() == b.get();
}
```

and etc... for the rest of the operators.

Then maybe I would like to implement another smart pointer `b_ptr`, which would give me 6 versions for every comparison operator (since I want it to also work with `a_ptr`), clearly not manageable.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

EDIT:

I should have probably mentioned that I want to create wrappers around smart pointers, in which case this question makes more sense, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
class a_ptr
{
public:
    const T* get() const {return p_.get();}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> p_;
};

template<typename T>
class b_ptr
{
public:
    const T* get() const {return p_.get();}
private:
    a_ptr<T> p_;
};
```

Comment: Concepts? Since we don't have those, you can use type traits or something.

Comment: If you have memory managed by a `shared_ptr` what is an `a_ptr` doing managing that same memory? Who really owns it?

Comment: That's a polynomial number of implementations, not exponential.

Comment: Now the question is "why on Earth are you wrapping smart pointers".

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: To add custom behavior, e.g. non-nullable smart pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
template<typename T> struct you_need_a_pointer_to_do_that{} unwrap_ptr(const T&);

template<typename U> U* unwrap_ptr(U* p) { return p; }

template<typename U> U* unwrap_ptr(const a_ptr<U>& p) { return p.get(); }

template<typename U> U* unwrap_ptr(const unique_ptr<U>& p) { return p.get(); }
```

...

```
template<typename T, typename PU> auto operator<(const a_ptr<T>& a, const PU& b) -> decltype(unwrap_ptr(a) < unwrap_ptr(b)) { return unwrap_ptr(a) < unwrap_ptr(b); }
```

The `decltype` bit rejects non-pointers due to SFINAE.  And the `unwrap_ptr` helper homogenizes the syntax for pointer access, with complexity only linear in the number of pointer types.

Comment: This seems to work, although without `compares_to_nothing` which purpose I am unsure of.

Comment: @ronag: It just guarantees that you get an error if `PU` infers as say `double`.  And now it's renamed so you get a better error.

Answer (score 5):

If any of these, except the one comparing two `a_ptr`, ever hold true, your program has a bug. So, just drop it. Smart pointer is smart, because it's responsible of managing the memory behind it. And you just cannot have *two* different smart pointers managing one piece of memory.

Consider `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. One destroys the pointer as soon as the owning smart pointer is destroyed. Second destroys the pointer only when *all* owning smart pointers are destroyed. I think it's fairly obvious it would quickly lead to double deletes and other fun stuff.

Comment: If the semantics of the smart pointer are like `shared_ptr`, couldn't you have any number of separate pointers that are essentially equivalent?

Comment: @bobby What happens when the last `shared_ptr` is gone? You're left with a bunch of `a_ptr`s sharing what was deleted by the last `shared_ptr`. You can make them have the same semantics, but what you really need is to have them *share the same memory and bookkeeping data*.

Comment: @bobbymcr: You'd have to poke into `shared_ptr` and sync reference counters. Just don't try stuff like this.

Comment: Cat, that's a very good point.  But it falls apart when you introduce `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `weak_ptr` doesn't own the memory. It really is just a complementary piece of `shared_ptr`, not a smart pointer on its own.

Comment: @Cat: And it's reasonable to compare a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`, isn't it?  Or, `a_ptr` could be a wrapper around `shared_ptr`, that does some extra stuff like logging.  That'd be compatible.

Comment: To be clear, I agree that what the OP is trying to do is not recommended. I'm just trying to get some clarity on your comment.

Comment: @Ben `weak_ptr` doesn't even act like a pointer or a smart pointer. It has no `operator*`, no `operator->` and no `get()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `std::weak_ptr` is not comparable to anything, even itself, actually.

Comment: Ok, well, composition is still a valid case that leads to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Ben Voigt is on the right track -- except of course we don't have concepts.

```
template<
    typename Lhs
    , typename Rhs
    , typename = typename std::enable_if<
        /* magic */
    >::type
>
bool
operator==(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
}
```

This must be in the same namespace of `a_ptr` and `b_ptr` for ADL to kick (so if they are in separate namespaces you need one version of each operator for each namespace).

There are several possibilities for the magic trait to work. The one that is conceptually the simplest is to have a trait that is specialized for each pointer type you care about:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_smart_pointer: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename D>
struct is_smart_pointer<std::unique_ptr<T, D>>: std::true_type {};
// and so on...
```

A more elaborate trait would check that the type supports a `get` member. Actually, we don't need a trait for that!

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator==(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
-> decltype( lhs.get() == rhs.get() )
{
    return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
}
```

This simple operator will be picked up by ADL, except that it will SFINAE itself out if one of the type doesn't support `get`, or if the comparison doesn't work.

Comment: I like the approach although it can also be done without relying on C++2011 feature (see my response: std::true_type and std::false_type can easily be implemented with C++2003).

Comment: I like the last approach, however I'm uncertain whether it is a good idea? It will allow it to work with any type which implement .get(), intended or not.

Comment: @ronag This all depends on the trait you want to use. Elaborate type traits + SFINAE is the closest we get to concepts. You could use a trait that detects `get` and checks that the return type is a pointer type for instance. In imaginary C++11 + concepts this would be the equivalent of `template<SmartPointer Lhs, SmartPointer Rhs> bool operator==(Lhs const&, Rhs const&);` or some such. How lax or how restrictive the SmartPointer concept needs to be depends on your needs (and as you point out, here it's quite lax).

Comment: Problem with this is that it can match objects which aren't smart pointers, as long as they have a `get()` member.  That's why I prefer to have a helper free function in the same namespace.

Comment: @BenVoigt Your approach is morally equivalent to the one where a trait is explicitly specialized for each type of interest.

Comment: @Luc: yes, except that it both provides the trait and the method for extracting the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just tag your smart pointer types and then implement a generic version which relies on at least one of the passed arguments to be tagged:

```
template <typename T> struct is_my_smartpointer: std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_my_smartpointer<a_ptr<T> >: std::true_type {};

template <typename S, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_my_smartpointer<S>::value || is_my_smartpointer<T>::value, bool>::type
operator== (S const& s, T const& t) {
    return s.get() == t.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit your custom smart pointer from an existing smart pointer. This way you won't have to implement any operators at all.
Also as as Cat Plus Plus said. You **cannot** have two smart pointer managing one piece of memory. So If you're implementing a smart pointer you should make sure that holds true. You should make `operator=` private so it cannot be copied into another location.

Comment: "Favor composition over inheritance".  Not everyone agrees, but anyone following that rule will need to implement (forwarding) comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as difficult as writing a sfinae trait for smart pointers. As soon as you get it, the solution is pretty straight forward, you don't need c++11 for this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace my {
template<class T>
class a_ptr
{
   T* t_;
public:
   typedef T element_type;
   element_type* get() const throw() { return t_; }
};

template<class T> class is_smart_ptr; // sfinae test for T::get()?

template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<
   is_smart_ptr<T>::value &&
   is_smart_ptr<U>::value,
   bool
>::type
operator==(const T& a, const U& b)
{
    return a.get() == b.get();
}
}

int main()
{
   my::a_ptr<int> a;
   std::shared_ptr<int> b;
   a == b;
}
```

And since std::shared_ptr already have operator==, you need to put your comparison operator in the same namespace where your smart pointer type is.